# Chocolatey ParamPackage is empty, even though the value is passed in debug mode

Tags: powershell, nuget, windows-installer, chocolatey

I am *attempting* to use Chocolatey to install an MSI package via Powershell. Following all the documentation and examples, my setup looks like this:

**chocolateyinstall.ps1**

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
$fileLocation = Join-Path $toolsDir 'installer.msi'

$pp = Get-PackageParameters

Write-Output ("Keys count is : ${pp}")

if (!$pp['defaultName']) { Write-Error "Please provide a default name"; exit -1; }

...
```

When I run this command:
`choco install .\st-installer.1.6.7.nupkg --force --params "'/defaultName:Bob'"`
the powershell throws my error:

*ERROR: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Please provide a default name*

However if I run the command with the -d switch, Powershell shows me: *packageParameters: '/defaultName:',*

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried every variation of quotations around the params, installation argument instead of param package. I don't know what else I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this before when testing packages locally, where my additional parameter values aren't referenced like you're seeing. I don't know *why* it happens, but don't reference a hard path to the `nupkg`. Instead, set the source parameter to the directory the package is in (relative path is fine), and then install the package by it's package ID as though you were installing from [Chocolatey.org](https://chocolatey.org). For example, if the package is in your current directory:

```
cinst -y st-installer --params "'/defaultName:Bob'" -s .
```

I'm not sure what version of Chocolatey you're on but if I try installing a package by pointing to the `nupkg` on disk, I get a warning about preferring the `-s` parameter and package ID instead of referencing the package file.

Comment: Yes, thank you! The -s . property was exactly what I needed for a local build.

Comment: If memory serves, I stumbled onto that solution by accident. Even though it's not recommended. It's still odd that specifying the full path to the package interferes with the `--params` values.